# Facebook in Awesomium component: Cookies required

Tags: facebook, cookies, awesomium

We use the Awesomium component to allow people to log in to their Facebook account. However since Saturday, on some places we receive an error when people try to login that says 'Cookies Required" "Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue".

[Facebook image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kuht6.jpg)

When I try to login from a webbrowser, it works fine. When I change the external IP address of the Router, it also works. The issue happens for all PC's in the network, so apparently it has to do something with the IP address.

When I disable the Javascript of the WebSession in code, the message is gone and the login works (but it doesn't load/show the following pages)

Anybody knows why this is happening on some (like 2% of our customers) networks, and why it works when I change the IP. First we were thinking we might have been blocked or something, but with a different component it does work, as well as in the browser.

Comment: Why are you using that component, instead of having users log in in a normal browser?

Comment: Because we are using the data we get (firstname, lastname, email, picture) etc in that application itself. It's a application to register yourself, if you use Facebook login, we already prefill some fields in further pages.

Comment: That doesn’t explain why it would need such a component, instead of doing the same in a normal browser.

Comment: Back when we created it, the default WPF component didn't work properly for our needs. We are reworking our applciation with this component now (and that works), but for existing customers that we want to update quickly to fix this issue, this is not an option.